# How do I access the contents of multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a multi-dimensional array so that I can eventually iterate through each array's contents.

The end goal is to be able to do something like this:

```
websiteURL[x]image[y].imageALT[z]
```

I think I can do this by creating a multi-dimensional array and adding properties where needed. If this is wrong, please let me know any possible alternatives and ignore the following question.

If it sounds about right, here's what I've got for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
    container = [['https://amazon.ca/logo.png', 'https://google.ca/logo/logo.png'], ['This is alt text 1.', 'This is alt text 2'], ['https://amazon.ca', 'https://google.ca']];

    var imageSRC = container[0]
    var imageALT = container[1]
    var imageCTA = container[2]

    imageSRC[0];
    container[0];
```

No output is given when I run this.

Comment: what output are you expecting? all you did are some variable assignments, if you want to see them in console you need to use console.log

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/412mbLc7/, provided you actually attempt to output something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right so far. The trick to it is to use the numbers in the square brackets next to each other.

```
container = [
// 0
    ['https://amazon.ca/logo.png', 'https://google.ca/logo/logo.png'],
// 1
    ['This is alt text 1.', 'This is alt text 2'],
// 2
    ['https://amazon.ca', 'https://google.ca']
];
```

So `container[0]` refers to the following:

```
['https://amazon.ca/logo.png', 'https://google.ca/logo/logo.png']
```

And `container[0][0]` refers to:

```
'https://amazon.ca/logo.png'
```

For complex things, I usually use Objects which are a bit friendly to work with.

```
container = [{
  image: 'https://amazon.ca/logo.png',
  alt: 'This is alt text 1.',
  url: 'https://amazon.ca',
},
{
  image: 'https://google.ca/logo/logo.png',
  alt: 'This is alt text 2',
  url: 'https://google.ca',
}]

console.log(container[1].alt) // 'This is alt text 2'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful to reference. I think I actually need to create an array of objects, not a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @JS26 No, your code works fine, as I demonstrated in my comment above

Comment: @j08691 My problem with this approach is that I'm not sure how to store dynamic information. For example, if I am filling out the same form using 5 different personas, and the form allows for up to 5 "favorite logo URLs" each, how can I store a variable amount of logo URLs and corresponding alt text + be able to call it at will?